# Wikipedia API Last Editor

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm accessing Wikipedia by its API to get the parsed version of an article.

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&section=0&format=json&prop=text&page=Stack_Overflow

Everything is working fine, except I'm trying to find who the last editor on the page was. Without making a separate request, is it possible to find this out?

I've tried accessing Wikipedias documentation but I'm not able to find anything that would seem pretty basic: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: WHy would it be pretty basic for a parse endpoint to return information that has nothing to do with parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via revision retrieval with parsing via https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Stack+Overflow&formatversion=2&rvprop=ids%7Ctimestamp%7Cflags%7Ccomment%7Cuser%7Ccontent&rvparse=1 ([sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&titles=Stack+Overflow&formatversion=2&rvprop=ids%7Ctimestamp%7Cflags%7Ccomment%7Cuser%7Ccontent&rvparse=1)), however unlike `action=parse` it doesn't support fine-tuned parsing options, like parsing only section 0 that your example uses. If you need to retrieve parsed lead sections of a bunch of pages, just retrieve metadata via one big `prop=revisions` request then do `action=parse` for individual pages. If your use case is different... ahem, no perfection in this life:P